# Cypress pragmatically login using API on a SPA application

Tags: api, vue.js, authentication, cypress, single-page-application

**What I would like to achieve:**
To login using the API and access admin dashboard.

**The problem:**
When I try to login via the API as an admin user, and then `cy.visit('https://mywebsite.com/dashboard')` I get redirected to ('https://mywebsite.com/') with 302 printed in cypress logs.

However, when done via the UI, it redirects correctly after submiting the login form.

**Code:**

```
  **API:**
```

```
    it("API: Admin user logs in via API and tries to view dashboard", () => {
        cy.adminLoginAPI()
        cy.visit(env.baseUrl + 'dashboard')
        cy.contains("Sales")
    });
```

```
  **UI:**
```

```
    it("UI: Admin user login and views dashboard", () => {
        cy.visit(env.baseUrl + 'login')
        cy.get("#email").type("email@email.com")
        cy.get("#password").type("password")
        cy.get('#submit-button').click()

        // Once the login form has been submitted in the UI, it automatically redirects to the admin dashboard.
        cy.contains("Sales")
    });
```

**What I've tried to far:**

Various bits, such as creating sessions, setting/getting cookies and running the `cy.visit()` within the `.then` block of the `cy.adminLoginAPI()` but no luck. I've also tried to pass auth token through `cy.visit()`

```
        cy.visit(env.baseUrl + 'dashboard', {
            header: {
                auth: {
                    "bearer": token
                },
            }
        })
       cy.contains("Sales")
```

Comment: Your application probably uses local storage to store the token generated by the login. When you login through the front end, the app logic handles token storing. If you use API functionality, you need to explicitly store your token in the appropriate location too, something like `window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', body.token)`. More can be found on using `cy.session()` for usage like this in [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Usage)